# Date Compare in HQL without timestamp

Tags: mysql, hibernate, date, datetime, hql

I have to compare two dates in hibernate hql query.
I am using java.util.Date in my java bean and using timestamp as datatype in mysql database.

```
select t from Task t where t.modifiedDate > t.endDate;
```

Above query compares time with date. What should i do to compare date in above query without time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the Hibernate documentations for available date functions

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

In section 14.10 notice this line

```
second(...), minute(...), hour(...), day(...), month(...), and year(...)
```

So this should work

```
... where year(t.endDate) > year(t.startDate) 
    and month(t.endDate) > month(t.startDate)
    and day(t.endDate) > day(t.startDate)
```

The solution reported as satisfying the question is

```
 ... where DATE(t.endDate) > (t.startDate)
```

Comment: This is giving me the comparison with month & year separately ... but i have to compare **full date** at a time like **06-09-2014**

Comment: It works with following change **where DATE(t.endDate) > (t.startDate)**

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I am editing the answer with your solution rather than leave the solution in the comments. That is the Stackoverflow way of doing things.

Comment: instead of t.startDate if we need to put a date as a name paramter then the query will be like, Date(t.endDate) <=  (:toDate), this one not working for me any help

Comment: @carbontax Is it allowed to use "where DATE(t.endDate) > DATE(:currentDate) " in hql query.That is using DATE() with the input parameter??

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution with the `date()` function does not seem to be pure SQL and does not work for me (using SQL Server). The original solution (comparing day, month and year individually) is a step in the right direction, but cannot be done in this way, as, e.g., for a date to be in the future, a day need not be greater if the month is greater, etc. The following SQL, however, should work:

```
( year(t.endDate) > year(t.startDate) )
or 
( year(t.endDate) = year(t.startDate) 
  and 
  month(t.endDate) > month(t.startDate) )
or 
( year(t.endDate) = year(t.startDate) 
  and
  month(t.endDate) = month(t.startDate) 
  and
  day(t.endDate) > day(t.startDate) )
```